# Geosoft GRD histograms do not save in layer file

Tags: histogram, geosoft

My colleagues and I are using ArcGIS 10.3 and 10.1 with the free Geosoft plug in.
When saving layers containing geosoft grd files we usually display using a percent clip which require the histogram to be built. The issue is that despite saving a layer file the histograms need to be rebuilt for most (but not all) grids each time Arc is started.
Has anyone had this issue and do you know how to sort it out?